# real- Analysis question about summation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irGPr.png)

I don't understand why $$a_{1} + 2a_{2} + ... + na_{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}ka_{k} = nS_{n} - \sum ^{n-1}_{k=1}S_{k}$$

I understand that $$nS_{n} = na_{1} + na_{2} + .....$$ then what is $$\sum ^{n-1}_{k=1}S_{k}$$

also how $$ \lim_{n -> \infty} \frac{\sum ^{n-1}_{k=1}S_{k}}{n-1} = a$$

please help me

Comment: I notice that you have not "accepted" any answers on your previous questions. if you find an answer helpful you can upvote it, and if it answers your question you might consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum^{n-1}_{k=1} S_k = (a_1) + (a_1 + a_2) + \dotsb + (a_1+a_2+\dotsb + a_k) + \dotsb + (a_1 + a_2 + \dotsb + a_{n-1})$$

Count the number of times each term occurs. $a_1$ occurs $n-1$ times. $a_2$ occurs $n-2$ times, etc.

Therefore by associativity of addition,

$$\sum^{n-1}_{k=1} S_k = (n-1)a_1 + (n-2)a_2 + \dotsb + a_{n-1}$$

Finally subtract this from $nS_n = na_1 + na_2 + \dotsb + na_n$ and you'll have $a_1 + 2a_2 + \dotsb + na_n$.

Comment: and the limit asked follows from $\sum^{n-1}_{k=1} S_k = (n-1)a_1 + (n-2)a_2 + \dotsb + a_{n-1}$ . Since $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum^{n-1}_{k=1} S_k=\sum^{n-1}_{k=1}\frac{n-k}{n-1}a_k$. Using $\frac{n-k}{n-1} \to 1$ as n goes to infinity, the limit is $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}a_k=a$.

Answer (score 1):

ziggurism has already explained what is $\displaystyle \sum ^{n-1}_{k=1}S_{k}$.

Now, perhaps you 've learnt CESARO's theorem in that book. This is not general form of that theorem but arithmetic mean version of that theorem. 
If $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = a$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_n}{n} = a$.
Here, it is the same thing (focus on $S_n$): $S_n = a_1 +a_2 +a_3 +...+a_n$. and $\sum^{n-1}_{k=1} S_k = (a_1) + (a_1 + a_2) + \dotsb + (a_1+a_2+\dotsb + a_k) + \dotsb + (a_1 + a_2 + \dotsb + a_{n-1})=S_1+S_2+S_3+...+S_{n-1}$.

Hence, $\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n = a$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{S_1+S_2+S_3+...+S_{n-1}}{n-1} = a$.
(If $n \to \infty$ then $n-1 \to \infty$)